# SIRS Stability Analysis

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have set up the following ODE's for a SIRS model:

> $$\frac{dS}{dt} =-\alpha SI + \zeta R$$
>   $$\frac{dI}{dt} = \alpha SI - \beta I - \rho I$$
>   $$\frac{dR}{dt} = \beta I - \zeta R$$
>   $$\frac{dD}{dt} = \rho I$$
>
> where
>
> 1. $\alpha = $ rate at which susceptibles become infected
> 2. $\beta = $ rate at which infected becomes recovered
> 3. $\zeta = $ rate at which members of recovery become susceptible again
> 4. $\rho = $ rate at which infected pass away

I am currently busy trying to analyse the stability of this system, but I'm having great difficulty so far (this is my first time working with SIR models and I'm self teaching).

I've posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041706/interperate-jacobian-determinant-stability-of-equilibriums) about this before with my attempt to do so using Jacobian.

Can anyone please have a look at this for me and provide me with some advice as to how I can go about in order to correctly analyse the stability of my model?

Comment: I think this question is very hard in general to do analytically. What you can do is use a computer to estimate the Lyapunov exponents along the orbit. You're computing the (logarithmic) rates at which a perturbation will grow in the various directions. If these exponents all appear to be non-positive, this is reasonable evidence for the stability of the system.

Comment: I second @AnthonyQuas on that. Even before "jumping" to Lyapunov constants, did you try some Matlab simulations? Since these are all ODE's, it'll be a two day project to write it, run it with different parameter sets and get a plausible sense.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, notice that the last equation is irrelevant for the analysis. After that, it is easily seen just by looking at the vector field that defines the ODE system on the boundaries of $\mathbb{R}^3_+$ that the solutions are always positive.

After that you can use the fact that $S+I+R$ is a decreasing function of $t$.

Comment: How is this related to the stability?

Comment: The last equation was brought in on purpose. I specifically introduced a Deceased class in order to explicitly display on the graphs the amount of people who were killed and how the size of the population gets decreased due to deaths.

Comment: I don't see why this answer has been down voted. From the little I know about SIR models, the state variables $S$, $I$ and $R$ ought to be constrained to be positive, that is, the solutions would not be extended to a solution outside $\mathbb{R}^3_+$. If this is the case, I believe the desired notion of stability would be that the equilibria set $\{S,I,R : I=0, R=0\}$ is stable if the solutions stop there. But as Memo Olicón pointed out, this is just the case.